# Git Push To New Repo Pushing Wrong Content

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, repository, bitbucket

I tried creating a new repo on Bitbucket and pushing all of my code to it, but for some reason it is pushing another folder's contents to the repo? I used `git status` and saw that there were many other files that were untracked yet completely irrelevant.

Things that I done so far -

- I have an existing Xcode project
- I cd into the folder
- I add my origin remote
- I `git push -u origin --all`
- I go to Bitbucket and see that another folder of mine has been pushed up

If I use the command `ls` in my directory, I see that only the files I need are there.

Comment: Git pushes commits that are int the repo, nothing more, so you may want to inspect what's really in therepo

Comment: This question could use more details in order to understand what the nature of the problem is, like commands used, etc.

Comment: @CharlesB My question is, how do I fix this problem?

Comment: @Cupcake Is that better? I edited my original post.

Comment: @MichaelScaria definitely better, could still use more info though. What branches do you have in your repo right now? The `--all` flag to `push` will push all of your branches. Is there a particular branch you're looking at on Bitbucket?

Comment: @Cupcake It should just be master, I just created the repo with the option to import existing code. Is there anyway you could undo the down vote, I was banned awhile ago, and now with this, I just got re-banned from asking questions...

Comment: @MichaelScaria I didn't downvote, so I can't undo anything. People are voting to re-open this though.

Comment: What is the folder you're seeing on Bitbucket? Make sure that the commit SHA1 of local and remote repos are the same

Comment: @CharlesB The folder I see is just another Xcode project folder in the same parent directory. I think somehow, git wants to add everything in my parent directory...

Comment: git just does what you tell him :) you must have added and committed these files at some point. There are several ways to undo this, can you identify the commits where the files got added?

Comment: @CharlesB Well my first attempt to correct this was to delete the repo on BB, remove the origin remote and start completely clean without using `git add .` and only push by using `git push -u origin --all`, somehow it still sends everything? I don't understand how git is getting files outside of the folder I'm committing things in and not pushing any files that are within the designated folder.

Comment: `git add .` doesn't commit, but add all files to be staged for commit. you have to commit before pushing... you'll want to check what gets committed by running `git status`, giving you a list of files

Comment: Yes, I did that turns out I hadn't initialized my git within that folder, so it's working now, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome; an upvote on one of my posts would be very welcome since you answered your own question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I hadn't initialized my git repository within that folder....
I used `git init` and it worked!